# finding roots of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots, substitution, cubics

I want to find the smallest positive root of equation: $$x^3-0.75x+b=0$$
when 
$$b =
\frac{1}{64}\left[(\sqrt{5}-1)(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})-(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\right]$$
I know value of this root is almost $0.01745240643$ but can any one find exact value by roots of integers? not approximate value in the form I wrote?
This equation has two other roots that I am not interested.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 5):

The hint:
$$\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}{4}\cdot\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}=$$
$$=\sin18^{\circ}\sin75^{\circ}-\cos18^{\circ}\cos75^{\circ}=-\cos93^{\circ}$$
and use $4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha=\cos3\alpha$.

I got that the smallest positive root it's $\sin1^{\circ}.$

Comment: Slight improvement.  Whrre you have functions of $18°$ render them instead as the complementary functions of $72°$, thus $\sin 18°\to\cos 72°$.  Thereby get $-\sin 3°$ directly and use the triple angle formula for sine from there.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Yes, of course, but I think the essence is the same.